# I'm not able to open "All" drop down from Amazon.ca page through selenium web driver using Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

Repro steps:

- Open amazon home page
- see the "ALL" drop-down option on the left top of the page.
- try to click on that (via Selenium WebDriver using Java)

Code:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("nav-search-scope nav-sprite"))).click();
         WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.className("nav-search-scope nav-sprite"));

new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("nav-search-scope nav-sprite"))).click();
         WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.className("nav-search-scope nav-sprite"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help you.

```
WebElement lelement=driver.findElement(By.className("nav-search-scope nav-sprite"));
Select oSelect = new Select(lelement);        
java.util.List <WebElement> elementCount = oSelect.getOptions(); // get all options from your drop down 
int iSize = elementCount.size();
String [] arrbtn= new String [iSize];           
for (int j = 0; j < iSize; j++) {
    arrbtn[j]=elementCount.get(j).getText();
    if(arrbtn[j]=="All"){ 
        oSelect .selectByVisibleText("All");
    }
}
```

Or You can use following method to select 'All' option.

```
public static void  getDropdownAllOption(WebDriver driver,WebElement lelement)
{
    Select oSelect = new Select(lelement);        
    java.util.List <WebElement> elementCount = oSelect.getOptions(); // get all options from your drop down 
    int iSize = elementCount.size();
    String [] arrbtn= new String [iSize];           
    for (int j = 0; j < iSize; j++) {
        arrbtn[j]=elementCount.get(j).getText();
        if(arrbtn[j]=="All"){ 
            oSelect .selectByVisibleText("All");
        }
    }

}
```

If you need to select drop down by visible text, you can use following method:

```
public static void selectByVisible(WebElement lelement,String selectValue) 
{
    WebElement mySelect =lelement;                  
    Select mySelectd= new Select(mySelect);         
    mySelectd .selectByVisibleText(selectValue);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.ca/");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

        driver.findElement(By.className("nav-search-scope")).click();
        Select selects = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("searchDropdownBox")));

        selects.getOptions().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getText() + "  is Displayed : " + e.isDisplayed()));
        selects.getOptions().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getText() + "  is Enabled : " + e.isEnabled()));
        selects.getOptions().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getText() + "  is Selected : " + e.isSelected()));

        driver.quit();
```